# How many customers to assign per IoT hub?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

We're developing an Azure IoT solution where each customer might have 5-15 devices and, in a year or two, we could easily have 500-1000 customers. We're having some debate on whether we want to assign a distinct hub for each customer or put as many customers as we think we can on each hub. There are pros and cons for each approach. Is there a best practice approach for determining this?

Comment: I do recommend to read the IoT Hub quotas and throttling document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the pricing for Azure IoT Hubs would push you to share hubs across customers with that few devices; i.e. an S1 hub w/ 1 unit is $50/month.  Multiplied by your 500-1K customers it's going to get very expensive to have hub/customer.  It also depends on what those devices are doing - if they are hitting throttling limits (as stated above already) you'll need to add either units, go up a SKU, or add additional hubs.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/iot-hub/